# Unique different rows per group

Tags: r, group-by, unique

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
    DF <- data.frame(x=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times=1, each=3),
            y=c(1,2,3))
```

which gives me

```
       x y
     1 A 1
     2 A 2
     3 A 3
     4 B 1
     5 B 2
     6 B 3
     7 C 1
     8 C 2
     9 C 3
```

In my original dataframe, each column represents a person. So I must match one single x for a single y, giving me something like

```
    x y
    A 1
    B 2
    C 3
```

In other words, I need y grouped by x, but the y must not be repeat along the dataframe.

Any ideas to help?

I really looked for it on stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything that would help me. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you provide more details as to how we would choose the `y` for the `x`? For instance, are you also allowing for (A,2), (B, 1), and (C,3)?

Comment: Sorry I didnt provide enough information. I just need that for each value in X, there is a Y that will appear again in any other X.
The order doesnt matter, if it is (A,2), (B,1) and (C,3), or (A,1), (B,2), (C,3). The important thing is that if 2 is with A, it must not be with B or C, and so on. Another important thing is that the they are not regular, they could be, for example

        x y
        A 1
        A 2
        B 1
        B 2
        B 3
        B 4
        C 1
        C 2
        C 3

Comment: *for each value in X, there is a Y that will NOT appear again in any other X

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `dplyr`, assuming that all groups have the same number of rows as the group numbers.

```
library(dplyr)

DF2 <- DF %>%
  mutate(Group_ID = group_indices(., x)) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(y = y[first(Group_ID)]) %>%
  ungroup()
DF2
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   x         y
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 A         1
# 2 B         2
# 3 C         3
```

Or we can use the following:

```
DF2 <- DF %>% filter(as.numeric(x) == y)
DF2
#   x y
# 1 A 1
# 2 B 2
# 3 C 3
```

This works because column `x` is factor. When we convert it to numeric, we can filter with the value in `y` directly.

Comment: Or using `DF %>% filter(match(x, unique(x)) == y)` if the column is not factor or `setDT(DF)[, .SD[.GRP ==y], x]`

Comment: @akrun Good suggestion. I never thought about `filter(match(x, unique(x)) == y)`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, they dont have the same number of rows as the group numbers. It could be anything, such as (A 1) (A 2) (B 1) (B 2) (B 3) (B 4) (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (D 1) (D 2) (D 3) (D 4) (D 5)